# Java - Using both the GUI and 2Dgraphics

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, 2d

I am trying to use java swing GUI at the same time I am drawing 2Dgraphics for the game I am creating. My goal is to have a drop down over the top of the graphics. Whenever i try to make a button or drop down in swing I cannot see it. This I believe is the 2Dgrahpics covering the swing elements.

This is my class decleration and my JFrame creation:

```
public class Main extends JFrame{

public Main(){
    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    setSize(1000,600);
    setTitle("Scaling Tests");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    setVisible(true);
```

This is how I am double buffering and drawing the graphics:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){

    dbImage = createImage(1000, 600);
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    draw(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight() , this);
    repaint();

}

public void draw(Graphics g){

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
```

I have tried to draw a JLabel like this in the constructor and the draw method:

```
JLabel mylabel = new JLabel();
    mylabel.setText("Hello World!");
    mylabel.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
    mylabel.setVisible(true); //unnecessary 
    this.add(mylabel);
```

This has not worked. I cannot see the Jlabel no matter where in the code I put it. I think there is some problem with the graphics covering it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are breaking the painting chain because you didn't invoke super.paint() so none of the child components are painted.

**However you should NOT override paint() on a JFrame.**

Instead, custom painting is done by overriding `paintComopnent()` on a `JPanel` and then you add the panel to the frame. And don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent(g) as the first statement in the method.

Then you can add the `JLabel` to the panel.

Also, never invoked repaint() in a painting method. This will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: After reading through it many times and doing more research I finally found my answer. It would have helped to have a code example, but I am forever grateful for your help and good programming to you.

Answer (score 0):

This works -except the label is all the background you have to use some layout manager to handle it

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Main extends JFrame{

public Main(){
setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
setSize(1000,600);
setTitle("Scaling Tests");
setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
JLabel mylabel = new JLabel();
mylabel.setText("Hello World!");
mylabel.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
add(mylabel);
setVisible(true);

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
Main m=new Main();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

Image dbImage = createImage(1000, 600);
Graphics dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
draw(dbg);
g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight() , this);

}

public void draw(Graphics g){

g.setColor(Color.red);
g.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);

}

}
```

Comment: You've broken the paint chain contract and you shouldn't really be extending from a `JFrame` let alone overriding it's `paint` method